# How to collect all exceptions of application when its work complete?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging

Run the application. Job. Close its window. I want to get a message containing information about exceptions in the order in which they occurred, and their content. How to collect them right ? The first idea is to use it:

```
       public class Collector
    {
        public static System.Collections.Concurrent.
            ConcurrentBag<Exception> ExceptionCollection;

    }

    public static void method1()
    {
        try { }
        catch (Exception ex) { Collector.ExceptionCollection.Add(ex); }
    }

    public static void methodN()
    {
        try { }
        catch (Exception ex) { Collector.ExceptionCollection.Add(ex); }
    }
```

What is more convenient options?

Comment: Would be helpful to see some of your code.

Comment: Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: I have already used try-catch block, but I dont understand how to collect results of this blocks if application not halted more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you are currently handling all those exceptions.

You can take a look at the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` ([documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx)) events. The latter should provide notification of all managed exceptions before they get passed to a normal exception handler.

Using either that or your current exceptions handlers you will have to store the information about the exceptions somewhere (either in a file, database, memory etc) and later do with it what you want.

Just note that there are some exceptions which you cannot really recover from and that an exception might occur during (because of) your collecting of the information.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Literal control and then with the expected flow of application (method to method) use a try catch block in the inside the catch add the exception message to the literal control.

Generally the flow would be constant during application runtime which'll help you understanding when/where exactly the error has occurred.

To make it more specific you can display the method name (where the error occurred) inside the catch block for testing and once you are sure about the logic flow you can replace the method name with the numbers.

(Provide some code if you are expecting a very generic answer).

Good Luck

Comment: You can see my code example(first my idea). Do you can tell me about more powerfull and usefull example ?